# Are there any other villains (aside from Doomsday) who've killed Superman?

Tags: dc, comics, superman

Doomsday famously [killed Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman) and is generally reckoned to be the only *true match* for Superman in a one-on-one fight.

[image]

**But are there any other villains who've killed Superman in the comic serials?**

Comment: [Toyman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Imom0ApY6QM) - Spoiler *he didn't really*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Superman was killed by **Murder Man**. And yes, that's his name. I'm not joking.

In [Superman #188](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_188) Zunial (AKA Murder Man) turned a kryptonite radio transmitter on Superman and killed him. Luckily he wasn't 'Uncle Ben dead' and one of his Superman robots was able to restore him to life.

[image]

---

Superman was killed by **Lex Luthor** in the '*What if...*' story called "[The Death of Superman!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Whatever_Happened_to_the_Man_of_Tomorrow%3F)". Tricky Luthor invented a cure for cancer that happened to be based on green Kryptonite. Once the world was saturated in the rays, he turned the beam full-strength on a highly weakened Superman, killing him instantly.

[image]

---

Superman was killed by **He-Man** in the crossover event [DC Universe vs. The Masters of the Universe](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/DC_Universe_vs._The_Masters_of_the_Universe_Vol_1_1) #02. It won't surprise you in the least that they found a way to bring him back two episodes later

> The Superman that died was from another reality

[image]

---

In the one-shot "[The Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kingdom_(comics))", Superman is killed *over and over again* (in a variety of exciting ways) by **Gog.**

**Gog's Sun Staff (repeatedly)**
[image]

**Stabbed to death with Kryptonian metal**
[image]

**A big bomb**
[image]

**A Kryptonian virus**
[image]